# Limit number of foreign keys based on how many foreign keys refer to that model in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to Django, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question!

So I have a model called Resident, which defines some basic characteristics for a tenant that would be renting out a room as such:

```
class Resident(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    room = models.ForeignKey('Room')
```

I also have a model called Room, which defines basic characteristics for a room that would be leased by a tenant:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    floor = models.IntegerField()
    beds = models.IntegerField()
```

How can I put a limit on the number of foreign keys from the Resident.room field based on the number of beds in a room, defined by Room.beds? For example, if `Room.beds == 2`, how can I limit the number of foreign keys allowed from Resident to be a max of 2?

Answer (score 3):

Using [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal, whenever you try creating a new `Resident` instance, you can first check the total number of *available* beds in the room at where the resident will stay:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Resident)
def resident_pre_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.room.beds == instance.room.resident_set.count():
        raise ValidationError('No bed left for: {}'.format(instance)
```

You can add above code at the end of your `models.py`. Please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/) for more information about how signals work in Django.

You can wrap up `.save()` method with `try/except:` to handle validation error gracefully in case you might want to pipe it into logger.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):    
    try:
      super(Resident, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    except ValidationError, exc:
        logger.error('Saving resident failed. Error: {}'.format(exc))
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I got it to raise the exception. But where would I handle the exception? Instead of crashing, how would I nicely display that there are no more beds available?

Answer (score 2):

I liked the way using the validator:

```
def restrict_amount(value):
    room = Room.objects.filter(pk=value).get()
    if room.resident_set.count() >= room.beds:
        raise ValidationError('Room already has maximal amount of residents (3)')


class Room(models.Model):
    number = models.IntegerField()
    floor = models.IntegerField()
    beds = models.IntegerField()


class Resident(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    room = models.ForeignKey('Room', validators=(restrict_amount, ))
```

Using validator will make Django handle it properly, for example, display an error in the admin panel.